# How to establish Firebird 2.5 service connection using trusted authentication and the RDB$ADMIN role?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Connections using trusted authentication can be established by passing `isc_dpb_trusted_auth` and `isc_spb_trusted_auth` in the respective parameter blocks when using Firebird 2.1.
The connected user will have administrative rights depending on their being member of a Windows group with administrative rights.

For Firebird 2.5 the role "rdb$admin" can be specified to connect with administrative rights to the database, provided the user has been granted permission to that role.

I want to establish a service connection with administrative rights, using that role, but haven't found a way yet to do it. The connection is made but I can't for example list database users, which I can when connecting as SYSDBA.

What combination of `isc_spb_trusted_auth`, `isc_spb_trusted_role` and `isc_spb_sql_role_name` or other parameter blocks do I need, and what parameters do I need to pass?

Comment: Have you looked at doc\README.trusted_authentication.txt in the Firebird folder? Because that simply says: _To use Windows trusted authentication, do not put user and password parameters
in DPB/SPB_

Comment: @Mark: There is no problem using trusted authentication per se, that works fine. I want to use the rdb$admin role though, and while I can simply pass it as the role when establishing a database connection I haven't been able to make it work when making a service connection. The connection is established, but it doesn't seem to have administrative rights. For example I can't list users, which I can when connecting as SYSDBA.

Comment: Looking at http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-security-rdbadmin.html it doesn't actually say anything about the admin role in connection to services, so I don't know. If you don't get an answer here you might want to ask the question on the Firebird-support mailinglist (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ ). What you might want to try is to specify isc_spb_dbname to a database (not the security database) where you have the admin role as well (as the doc says in _Using the RDB$ADMIN role in the security database_

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a role and a user regarding where appropriate data are stored. The former is stored inside database in the RDB$ROLES table. The latter is stored in a special separate database file named security2.fdb, which usually lays in a Firebird directory.

When attaching to a service manager through Firebird API particular database is not known yet. Only server name is specified. Because of this you can not use roles. At this point the server simply doesn't know from what database to read role credentials.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this can't be done? Or could it, if a path to a database were given?

Comment: Most of firebird services act upon a database (backup, restore, validate etc.) But internally there is an attachment to service manager as a first thing and only then start of a selected service. See isc_service_attach function http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_178. It doesn't know anything about database. Only host name.

Answer (score 0):

The only service accepting role parameter in FB2.5 is users' management - that's how services work since interbase 6. Ability to use it for other services will be present starting with FB3.